# How can I embed VaniilaJS into React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have open source library that I want to use. the library wrote in clean vanilla js:
follow their docs, if I want to use the library:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="./jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="./kinetic-v5.1.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="./inchlib-1.2.0.js"></script>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function() { //run when the whole page is loaded
            var inchlib = new InCHlib({"target": "inchlib",
                            "width": 800,
                            "height": 1200,
                            "column_metadata_colors": "RdLrBu",
                            "heatmap_colors": "RdBkGr",
                            "max_percentile": 90,
                            "middle_percentile": 60,
                            "min_percentile": 10,
                            "heatmap_font_color": "white",
                             text: 'biojs'});
        inchlib.read_data_from_file("/microarrays.json");
        inchlib.draw();

    inchlib.onAll(function(name){
        console.log(name + " event triggered");
    });

});
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="heatmaps" style="margin:auto; align-items: center; margin-left:25%;">
            <div id="inchlib"></div>
        </div>
        <div ></div>
    </body>
 </html>
```

The file inchlib-1.2.0.js contains the main logic and js code. I want to build react project and use this library there. How can I achieve this goal?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

export default class App extends Component {
  render () {
    return (
   <div>
      <div>
      </div>
   </div>
)
  }
}
```

Comment: so you don't need a jquery you need to fire inchlib at the page load or the library require jquery to work ?

Answer (score 2):

You can create custom hook with useEffect. In useEffect you should paste your code. You can insert html elements, add event listeners and so on.

```js
useLibrary.js

import { useEffect } from "react";

const useLibrary = () => {

  useEffect(() => {
    $.getScript("inchlib-1.2.0.js", function(){
       var inchlib = new InCHlib({"target": "inchlib",
                          "width": 800,
                          "height": 1200,
                          "column_metadata_colors": "RdLrBu",
                          "heatmap_colors": "RdBkGr",
                          "max_percentile": 90,
                          "middle_percentile": 60,
                          "min_percentile": 10,
                          "heatmap_font_color": "white",
                           text: 'biojs'});
      inchlib.read_data_from_file("/microarrays.json");
      inchlib.draw();
      inchlib.onAll(function(name){
          console.log(name + " event triggered");
      });
    });
  }, []);


};

export default useLibrary;


App.js

import useLibrary from ".useLibrary";
export default class App extends Component {
  useLibrary();
  render () {
    return (
   <div>
      <div class="heatmaps" style="margin:auto; align-items: center; margin-left:25%;">
        <div id="inchlib"></div>
      </div>
   </div>
)
  }
}
```

But I warn you that this is a big crutch.

Comment: I treid but I got this error: src\App.js Line 7:23: 'InCHlib' is not defined no-undef

Comment: you use jQuery, so you can insert script in useEffect hook this way $.getScript("inchlib.js", function(){
    var inchlib = new InCHlib({ ...
});

Answer (score 0):

Well If I were to do the same thing then I would paste the script tags as you've done in your html file

```
<head>
    <script src="./jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./kinetic-v5.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./inchlib-1.2.0.js"></script>
    <script>
 </head>
```

For accessing an object into react app, Create a file named Inchlib.js in same directory as is your app.js

Contents of `Inchlib.js` should be

```
export default window.InCHlib;
```

Import the default export into your `app.js`

```
import InCHlib from "./inchlib";

function App() {
    console.log(InCHlib); // prints the InCHlib object
    return "hello";
}
```

Note: Although this should work, there might be a better way to do this. Also using global objects in react code is not usually a preferred option.

Hopefully this would help.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you're gonna do with the library you want to integrate with. Checkout this as a base reference: [Integrating with other libraries](https://reactjs.org/docs/integrating-with-other-libraries.html).

If you're gonna manipulate DOM elements you'll gonna need a reference to them. In this case checkout this: [Refs and the DOM](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html).

If the library provides some general logic, you have no problem using it anywhere throughout your code or more specifically in effects.

As **inchlib** is a visual element library, you'll need to go the first route and get a reference to a specific DOM element. As already noted, checkout **Refs** from react docs.

Alternative solution is to wrap the whole library usage in your own react component.

Comment: the best option is to wrap the whole library with my own react component, but I cant understand how can I import my js file? .

Answer (score 0):

Just add the **Libraries and Scripts** you want in the **public/index.html** file in your react project.

Comment: and then how can I import my js file?

Comment: put the new.js file into the public folder then add this <script src="new.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

create `loadScript` function:

```
 function loadScript(src, position, id) {
  if (!position) {
    return;
  }

  const script = document.createElement('script');
  script.setAttribute('async', '');
  script.setAttribute('id', id);
  script.src = src;
  position.appendChild(script);
}
```

in Component:

```
 export default function GoogleMaps() {

    const loaded = React.useRef(false);

     if (typeof window !== 'undefined' && !loaded.current) {
       if (!document.querySelector('#google-maps')) {
         loadScript(
           'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBwRp1e12ec1vOTtGiA4fcCt2sCUS78UYc&libraries=places',
           document.querySelector('head'),
           'google-maps',
         );
       }

       loaded.current = true;
     }
  }
```

now you can access `window.google`

here is a [example](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-autocomplete/#GoogleMaps.js)