# How can I use third js library in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an open source that wrote in vanilla js library:
https://www.openscreen.cz/software/inchlib/home/

I want to import the library to my react project.
The inchlib-1.2.0.js file doesn't contain any export functions/variables and it depends on several libraries such as Jquery and Kinetic.

First I tried to put my inchlib-1.2.0.js file into public dir and then add the all three scripts in my index.html

this is the inital code at my inchlib-1.2.0.js file, and I should initate my InCHlib object via this constructor:

```
var InCHlib;

(function($){
  
  InCHlib = function(settings){
      var self = this;
      self.user_settings = settings;
      self.target_element = $("#" + settings.target);
      var target_width = self.target_element.width();
      self.target_element.css({"position": "relative"});
.
. // more code
.
}(jQuery));
```

my index.html:

```
<html>
    <head>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.js" integrity="sha256-lCf+LfUffUxr81+W0ZFpcU0LQyuZ3Bj0F2DQNCxTgSI=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="http://openscreen.cz/software/inchlib/static/js/kinetic-v5.1.0.min.js"></script>
      <script src="./inchlib-1.2.0.js" type="text/JavaScript"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
      <div id="root">
      </div>
    </body>
 </html>
```

my App.js component:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './App.css';
function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
  var inchlib = InCHlib({"target": "inchlib",
    "width": 800,
    "height": 1200,
    "column_metadata_colors": "RdLrBu",
    "heatmap_colors": "RdBkGr",
    "max_percentile": 90,
    "middle_percentile": 60,
    "min_percentile": 10,
    "heatmap_font_color": "white",
     text: 'biojs'});
  inchlib.read_data_from_file("../microarrays.json");
  inchlib.draw();
  });
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
            <div id="inchlib"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
  );
  }
```

I got this error :   `'InCHlib' is not defined  no-undef`

My second attemp was just import the js file via my App component, and put the inchlib-1.2.0.js inside my src dir.
but then react cannot load the query script and Kinetic script from my index.html.

```
src\inchlib\dist\inchlib-1.2.0.js
  Line 162:29:    '$' is not defined            no-undef
  Line 565:32:    'Kinetic' is not defined      no-undef
  Line 570:30:    'Kinetic' is not defined      no-undef
  Line 578:31:    'Kinetic' is not defined      no-undef
  Line 589:23:    'Kinetic' is not defined      no-undef
  Line 597:29:    'Kinetic' is not defined      no-undef
  Line 602:31:    'Kinetic' is not defined      no-undef
  Line 608:32:    'Kinetic' is not defined      no-undef
  Line 615:31:    'Kinetic' is not defined      no-undef
  Line 620:32:    'Kinetic' is not defined      no-undef
  Line 626:24:    'Kinetic' is not defined      no-undef
  Line 634:34:    'Kinetic' is not defined      no-undef
  Line 639:33:    'Kinetic' is not defined      no-undef
  Line 645:23:    'Kinetic' is not defined      no-undef
  Line 649:32:    'Kinetic' is not defined      no-undef
  Line 660:24:    'Kinetic' is not defined      no-undef
  Line 686:5:     '$' is not defined            no-undef
  Line 741:7:     '$' is not defined            no-undef
  Line 759:13:    'id' is not defined           no-undef
  Line 760:22:    'id' is not defined           no-undef
  Line 768:13:    'id' is not defined           no-undef
  Line 769:30:    'id' is not defined           no-undef
  Line 819:57:    'len' is not defined          no-undef
  Line 819:80:    'len' is not defined          no-undef
  Line 1069:24:   'Kinetic' is not defined      no-undef
  Line 1112:30:   'Kinetic' is not defined      no-undef
  Line 1113:39:   'Kinetic' is not defined      no-undef
  Line 1125:35:   'Kinetic' is not defined      no-undef
  Line 1211:30:   'Kinetic' is not defined      no-undef
  Line 1212:28:   'Kinetic' is not defined      no-undef
  Line 1233:42:   'Kinetic' is not defined      no-undef
  Line 1272:16:   'keys' is not defined         no-undef
  Line 1272:63:   'len' is not defined          no-undef
  Line 1272:69:   'keys' is not defined         no-undef
  Line 1272:86:   'len' is not defined          no-undef
  Line 1273:13:   'keys' is not defined         no-undef
  Line 1280:16:   'len' is not defined          no-undef
  Line 1280:44:   'len' is not defined          no-undef
  Line 1384:9:    'i' is not defined            no-undef
  Line 1384:16:   'keys' is not defined         no-undef
  Line 1384:53:   'len' is not defined          no-undef
  Line 1384:59:   'keys' is not defined         no-undef
  Line 1384:72:   'i' is not defined            no-undef
  Line 1384:76:   'len' is not defined          no-undef
  Line 1384:81:   'i' is not defined            no-undef
  Line 1385:9:    'node' is not defined         no-undef
  Line 1385:32:   'keys' is not defined         no-undef
  Line 1385:37:   'i' is not defined            no-undef
  Line 1386:12:   'node' is not defined         no-undef
  Line 1387:23:   'node' is not defined         no-undef
  Line 1397:13:   'i' is not defined            no-undef
  Line 1397:20:   'i' is not defined            no-undef
  Line 1397:49:   'i' is not defined            no-undef
  Line 1398:27:   'i' is not defined            no-undef
  Line 1405:13:   'i' is not defined            no-undef
  Line 1405:20:   'keys' is not defined         no-undef
  Line 1405:61:   'len' is not defined          no-undef
  Line 1405:67:   'keys' is not defined         no-undef
  Line 1405:80:   'i' is not defined            no-undef
  Line 1405:84:   'len' is not defined          no-undef
  Line 1405:89:   'i' is not defined            no-undef
  Line 1406:47:   'keys' is not defined         no-undef
  Line 1406:52:   'i' is not defined            no-undef
  Line 1529:32:   'Kinetic' is not defined      no-undef
  Line 1530:34:   'Kinetic' is not defined      no-undef
  Line 1543:11:   'key' is not defined          no-undef
  Line 1544:41:   'key' is not defined          no-undef
  Line 1545:48:   'key' is not defined          no-undef
  Line 1552:11:   'y1' is not defined           no-undef
  Line 1555:101:  'y1' is not defined           no-undef
  Line 1558:15:   'y1' is not defined           no-undef
  Line 1558:20:   'y1' is not defined           no-undef
  Line 1566:41:   'Kinetic' is not defined      no-undef
  Line 1584:21:   'Kinetic' is not defined      no-undef
  Line 1692:23:   'width' is not defined        no-undef
  Line 1693:23:   'x' is not defined            no-undef
  Line 1693:54:   'width' is not defined        no-undef
  Line 1694:23:   'y' is not defined            no-undef
  Line 1695:40:   'x' is not defined            no-undef
  Line 1695:45:   'y' is not defined            no-undef
  Line 1723:15:   'width' is not defined        no-undef
  Line 1724:15:   'x' is not defined            no-undef
  Line 1724:46:   'width' is not defined        no-undef
  Line 1725:15:   'y' is not defined            no-undef
  Line 1726:32:   'x' is not defined            no-undef
  Line 1726:37:   'y' is not defined            no-undef
  Line 1735:21:   'Kinetic' is not defined      no-undef
  Line 1789:19:   'i' is not defined            no-undef
  Line 1789:26:   'i' is not defined            no-undef
  Line 1789:44:   'i' is not defined            no-undef
  Line 1790:39:   'i' is not defined            no-undef
  Line 1805:18:   'keys' is not defined         no-undef
  Line 1805:65:   'len' is not defined          no-undef
  Line 1805:71:   'keys' is not defined         no-undef
  Line 1805:88:   'len' is not defined          no-undef
  Line 1806:11:   'leaf_id' is not defined      no-undef
  Line 1806:21:   'keys' is not defined         no-undef
  Line 1807:37:   'leaf_id' is not defined      no-undef
  Line 1811:64:   'leaf_id' is not defined      no-undef
  Line 1849:22:   'Kinetic' is not defined      no-undef
  Line 1873:31:   'Kinetic' is not defined      no-undef
  Line 1881:18:   'len' is not defined          no-undef
  Line 1881:61:   'len' is not defined          no-undef
  Line 1885:18:   'len' is not defined          no-undef
  Line 1885:65:   'len' is not defined          no-undef
  Line 1897:18:   'len' is not defined          no-undef
  Line 1897:50:   'len' is not defined          no-undef
  Line 1967:22:   'Kinetic' is not defined      no-undef
  Line 1973:24:   'Kinetic' is not defined      no-undef
  Line 1989:33:   'Kinetic' is not defined      no-undef
  Line 2009:26:   'Kinetic' is not defined      no-undef
  Line 2029:35:   'Kinetic' is not defined      no-undef
  Line 2444:36:   'Kinetic' is not defined      no-undef
  Line 2516:39:   'Kinetic' is not defined      no-undef
  Line 2810:28:   'Kinetic' is not defined      no-undef
  Line 2827:28:   'Kinetic' is not defined      no-undef
  Line 2853:11:   'filter_list' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 2864:19:   'filter_list' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 2864:33:   'filter_list' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 2868:76:   'filter_list' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 2910:34:   '$' is not defined            no-undef
  Line 2911:36:   '$' is not defined            no-undef
  Line 2916:19:   '$' is not defined            no-undef
  Line 2920:19:   '$' is not defined            no-undef
  Line 2926:11:   '$' is not defined            no-undef
  Line 2935:14:   '$' is not defined            no-undef
  Line 2937:17:   '$' is not defined            no-undef
  Line 2943:17:   '$' is not defined            no-undef
  Line 2997:17:   '$' is not defined            no-undef
  Line 3026:21:   '$' is not defined            no-undef
  Line 3041:20:   '$' is not defined            no-undef
  Line 3042:20:   '$' is not defined            no-undef
  Line 3051:22:   '$' is not defined            no-undef
  Line 3055:27:   '$' is not defined            no-undef
  Line 3087:7:    '$' is not defined            no-undef
  Line 3114:25:   '$' is not defined            no-undef
  Line 3121:23:   '$' is not defined            no-undef
  Line 3124:18:   'keys' is not defined         no-undef
  Line 3124:53:   'len' is not defined          no-undef
  Line 3124:59:   'keys' is not defined         no-undef
  Line 3124:76:   'len' is not defined          no-undef
  Line 3125:15:   'keys' is not defined         no-undef
  Line 3134:18:   'keys' is not defined         no-undef
  Line 3134:53:   'len' is not defined          no-undef
  Line 3134:59:   'keys' is not defined         no-undef
  Line 3134:76:   'len' is not defined          no-undef
  Line 3135:15:   'keys' is not defined         no-undef
  Line 3158:7:    '$' is not defined            no-undef
  Line 3159:7:    '$' is not defined            no-undef
  Line 3160:7:    '$' is not defined            no-undef
  Line 3161:7:    '$' is not defined            no-undef
  Line 3162:7:    '$' is not defined            no-undef
  Line 3169:27:   '$' is not defined            no-undef
  Line 3172:20:   '$' is not defined            no-undef
  Line 3173:20:   '$' is not defined            no-undef
  Line 3182:33:   '$' is not defined            no-undef
  Line 3185:22:   '$' is not defined            no-undef
  Line 3218:20:   '$' is not defined            no-undef
  Line 3245:20:   '$' is not defined            no-undef
  Line 3246:20:   '$' is not defined            no-undef
  Line 3255:19:   '$' is not defined            no-undef
  Line 3256:19:   '$' is not defined            no-undef
  Line 3257:7:    '$' is not defined            no-undef
  Line 3342:22:   '$' is not defined            no-undef
  Line 3636:5:    '$' is not defined            no-undef
  Line 3640:7:    '$' is not defined            no-undef
```

Any suggestions please?

Comment: This is kind of an antipattern. React really wants to manage the DOM for you. Now you pull a library that manipulates the DOM without reacts consent. If I needed something like this and there was no way to use a proper react library, I would separate the React app and this thing on my page. Each one can control their own corner.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I embed VaniilaJS into React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65459254/how-can-i-embed-vaniilajs-into-react)

Answer (score 1):

InCHlib seems to use outdated method of populating a global variable to make itself visible to your application instead of making itself a module. So you can access it with `InCHlib` or `window.InCHlib`.

Your first attempt might work if you add a type definition for InCHlib, assuming you are using typescript, preferably put it on `window.InCHlib`.

Another option that could be possible is to add kinetic and jquery to your npm/yarn modules since those two have been made into modules, and add the correct imports to `InCHlib.js` and possibly convert `InCHlib` to a module.

```js
// at the end of InCHlib
module.exports = InCHlib;
```

Comment: but the problem is during my import the InChlib. In react I cant import files outside the src directory. and my inchlib file located at public directory

Comment: Don't combine both ways, the first options is to use `InCHlib.js` as is, it will populate a global variable that you can access when you link it in html, you just need to add a type definition to it, there is no need to import anything, just use `window.InCHlib`.