# How to link a js file in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to link a local file `description.js` which is in the same folder. How can I link it to this file? The purpose is to open that file as a page when the user clicks on read more button.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import image from './images/pk.png';
//import Description from './description';
<script type="text/javascript" src="description.js"></script>

export default class Box extends Component {
  render() {
    let {name,code,numCode,amb,fire,pol,dispatch}=this.props;
    return (
      <div className='box'>
        <div className='e_body'>
                  <img className="countryImg" src={image} alt='Fail to load'/>
            <h5>{name}</h5>
            <p>ISO-Code: {code}<br/>ISO-Numeric: {numCode}</p>
            <a href="description.js" className='btn btn-sm btn-warning'>Read More</a>
            
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Please post your description.js file content , so that we can help better

Comment: Does this solves your problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65459254/how-can-i-embed-vaniilajs-into-react

Comment: Thanks everyone for your response.
I don't know why I was having errors with react navigation so I used routes. I used in nav-bar as well and wanted to try navigation.
But this problem can be solved using routes.
I used ```Link``` in above code and added the ```route``` in ```App.js```

Answer (score 0):

```
first define routes in App.js
and rename your file with capital description.js -> Description.js
App.js  should look like:
   

      
    import React from "react";
    import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
    
    const App = ({}) => {
      const navigate = useNavigate();
      return (
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Your Home Compoenent />} />
            <Route path="/description" element={<Description />} />
          </Routes>
        </BrowserRouter>
      );
    };

Your component

   

 

import React, { Component } from "react";
    import image from "./images/pk.png";
    
    import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
    
    const Box = ({ name, code, numCode, amb, fire, pol, dispatch }) => {
      const navigate = useNavigate();
      return (
        <div className="box">
          <div className="e_body">
            <img className="countryImg" src={image} alt="Fail to load" />
            <h5>{name}</h5>
            <p>
              ISO-Code: {code}
              <br />
              ISO-Numeric: {numCode}
            </p>
            <button
              className="btn btn-sm btn-warning"
              onClick={() => {
                navigate("/description");
              }}
            >
              Read More
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    };
```

Comment: Getting this Error:                                                                                                            
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-native' in 'E:\React\my-app\node_modules\@react-navigation\native\lib\module'
ERROR in ./node_modules/@react-navigation/native/lib/module/Link.js 2:0-46
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-native' in 'E:\React\my-app\node_modules\@react-navigation\native\lib\module'

Comment: You have to install react-router-dom  package  if you're using React js you can install
 with: yarn add react-router-dom or npm install --save   react-router-dom
but since you use React Native check documentation here:
https://v5.reactrouter.com/native/guides/quick-start

Answer (score -1):

You have to use 'Routes' for this .
then do

import Usenavigate from react-router-dom

```
const navigate = useNavigate();
```

inside onClick callback function

```
navigate('/Description')
```